# Preload FK relation in different column Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have Django models that looks like this

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"))

class Feature(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(_("Name"))

class AddOn(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature)
```

Given that I have an instance of Customer e.g

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
```

How do I get all the labels in feature in one query to avoid N+1 query?

For now what I've done is:

```
[addon.feature.label for addon in self.addon_set.all()]
```

But I think for each `addon.feature` will create a query that is not very optimized if there is a lot of addon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values)/[values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to get all labels in a single query

```
self.addon_set.values_list('feature__label', flat=True)
```

EDIT: Example of the ManyToManyField

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"))
    features = ManyToManyField('Feature', through='AddOn')

class Feature(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(_("Name"))

class AddOn(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature)
```

You can then perform queries like `customer_obj.features.all()` or `feature_obj.customers.all()` and it won't affect your ability to still query the AddOn model

Comment: Very helpful! Need to wait for 5 minutes to accept it 

Comment: @euclid135 You may find it useful to add a ManyToManyField from Customer to Feature or vice-versa using your AddOn model as a "through" table. It can simplify quite a lot of these types of queries

Comment: I see, instead of adding a new Class, I need to add a field on the model that define ManytoMany. I am quite new to this Django model, how is a through model works? I also need to query from the Addon Model, so having that model is also quite helpful

Comment: @euclid135 Added an example to the answer. With your current model design adding the ManyToManyField won't do anything but give you a few helpers/shortcuts

Comment: Accepted and Upvoted. Thanks!